# How do I create a catalogue list that links through to my individual product nodes?

Tags: views, commerce

I have taken Ryan Szrama's advice from [a question I asked on how to display products](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-do-i-get-my-products-to-display-in-drupal-commerce) and have now got that working. I have also built a catalogue list of all my products using views.
I now need to link the two up, so that if a user views the catalogue they can click through from there to the appropriate individual product node. How do I do this, or am I missing something?

To be specific: I have a view called 'catalogue' that is a list of books using a table, and I have a view 'book' that is an unformatted list that contains more detail on each book (like cover image, author etc). This view returns all books initially. I want the title in the list to link through to the book view and filter that view using ISBN (SKU) for an individual book. I can create the link, but I am not sure how to correctly format it. Currently the link looks like this: /book?isbn=123456789 (I have also tried /book?sku=123456789). This link just returns a full unfiltered list of the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I'm not using D7 yet, but Views has settings to turn fields within a node (your product nodes) into links to the originating node. Just go to your View that is your grid of products, check out the individual Fields you use, in their settings some of them (if not all of them) should have an option to turn the field into a link back to the original node.

Comment: I understand what you are saying in principle, but don't know exactly what to do in practice. I'm refining the question above to be more specific.

Comment: The correct format is: /book/123456789 for the filtered view.

I discovered this after going through this views tutorial on NodeOne. Really made things a whole lot clearer