# How do I add an additional submit handler in commerce checkout form?

Tags: commerce, forms

How do I add an additional submit handler? I have tried this but it did not work.

```
function c_coupon_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
  switch($form_id) {
     case 'commerce_checkout_form_review':
      drupal_set_message($form_id . '_form submit');
      $form['#submit'][] = 'c_coupon_review_submit';
  }
}

function c_coupon_review_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('submitted');
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.

The problem is that Drupal Commerce has defined the submit action on the buttons that is clicked, which will be used instead of the submit handlers defined on the form itself. So you need to add your submit handlers to the buttons (Cancel, Continue) that you want to use your submit function.

```
$form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][]='c_coupon_review_submit';
```

Comment: so how can I add the submit handler to the Continue button?

Comment: I believe it's `$form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][] = ..` You can inspect the form variable and find out.

Comment: But I want that my submit function should execute first than its own submit function? How could I do this?

Comment: That's a new question. Comments is not meant for asking/answering questions.

Answer (score 7):

To quickly answer Ahmad's refined question - how to add his custom submit function BEFORE other submit functions:

```
if ( empty($form['buttons']['continue']['#submit']) ) {
    $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'] = array(); // just in case
}
array_unshift($form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'],'c_coupon_review_submit');
```

Comment: For reference, the refined question is in the comments of the answer from googletorp.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to add extra submit handler to a form. It worked for me:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'xyz') {
            $form['#submit'][] = 'webform_extra_submit_test';
        }
    }

function webform_extra_submit_test($form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
    $user_id = $user->uid; 
    // do code here $form_state['values'] etc...
}
```