# Webform does not submit, instead redirects to self

Tags: webforms, forms

My soon-to-be production Drupal site's Webforms have stopped saving submissions; instead it comes back to the same page, complete with the inputted values. I do not have a timeline when it stopped working. In a sandbox environment, Webform 7.x-3.17 works fine.

**I'm looking for some suggestions to further debug.**

I've tried the following, but to no success:

- Disabling any modules that refer to Webform (notably [Webform Template](http://drupal.org/project/webform_template) and [Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation), and my own custom module that had been using `hook_form_alter`).
- Upgrading to the latest Webform (yes I remembered to use update.php).
- [Based on documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property), combining `hook_form_alter($form, &$form_state)` with `array_unshift($form['#submit'],'my_custom_submit')` to insert a custom callback, where I called [`drupal_build_form($form['form_id']['#value'],$form_state)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) to emulate a submission.
- Obviously flushing caches consistently.
- Ensuring that the Webform is published.
- Writing a bare-bones module to simply monitor `$form_state['executed']` (it always returns false).
- Checking my server's `error_log` both on SSH and FTP.
- Checking Reports > Recent log messages.
- **New:** Tried disabling & uninstalling Webform, deleting old Webform files, and installing a fresh new version of Webform; no good.

I'm pretty sure the issue is not isolated to Webform, so it wouldn't make sense to post to their issue queue.

What other debugging methods can I pull out to help crush this bug? If I disable every module without uninstalling, is an entire FTP backup necessary or just SQL?

**EDIT: Some more things I've tried as per suggestions (unsuccessfully)**

- Explicitly defining $cookie_domain and $base_url in settings.php
- Looking through Trigger and Action modules for any potential misfiring redirects

Comment: Have you checked for a trigger/action or rule that causes a redirect that may be misfiring?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Unfortunately no, there are no leads in the Trigger or Action module UI pages.

Comment: Make sure you are using the proper settings.php, that the values of $base_url and $cookie_domain are set properly, I recommend using multiple settings folders for your different settings. Each has their own database, $base_url and $cookie domain settings. Makes troubleshooting easier, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I have never had any problem with the Webform module, but if it happened to me I would double check sites/default/setting.php to see if there are any settings for an explicit `$base_url` or `$cookie_domain`. The latter is much improbable, since you would probably have problems with logging in.

Comment: Dang. I tried adding this to the bottom of sites/default/settings.php: http://pastebin.com/94PBeeiG. That did not work, but thanks for the response! (I'm certainly running desperate.)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are using the Boost module, that was happening to me and the problem was in the .htaccess file, check my solution here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207102/11424

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Like Dennis, the problem was caused by putting a URL alias on the webform node. When I removed the alias and did a full URL then it worked just fine. In my case, there was a conflict because my chosen URL alias was equal to a directory name on my site.  So I could use a different alias and it worked fine.  I just can't use the alias I wanted, unless I rename the conflicting directory on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I was just getting exactly this issue. I found that the problem was that the form was being altered in a way that prevented webforms from understanding it. As far as I could tell, the $form_state was not being affected by the changes, but altering the $form was still enough to break the whole thing.

I haven't found the workaround yet. I'll update my answer if I do.

Update: For my workaround, I used the #prefix and #suffix to add markup to elements instead of putting them in form containers. This fixed the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91506/webform-does-not-submit-redirects-to-self-when-file-field-or-page-break-added), whereby the presence of certain fields remove the `#node` element, which ruins submission / validation.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my two cents worth here.  I had the same issue on a dev site.  The site will go live soon, but I was checking the functionality and got this very same issue.

The problem was caused by putting a URL alias on the webform node.  When I removed the alias and did a full URL (mysite.com/?q=node/8) then it worked just fine.

Also, I don't have clean URLs enabled so that might fix the issue with the URL alias.

But I wanted to throw this out to anyone else with the issue . . .