# Output form result after form_submit

Tags: 7, forms

I have custom module, where after form_submit, i do some calculations, and get result of those calculations in a variable.

After i hit "submit", i can output those calculations with **drupal_set_message** , but i would like to format results (array), and print it bellow the submit button. How can i output resulting variable bellow the form or in the form, after submission ?

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

$a=$b+$c;

// on submit, i would like to print/format $a on the reloaded form page

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is use something like `$form_state['temporary']` in your `myMod_submit` function. Set `$form_state['temporary'] = $someValue` and rebuild your form. You also want your `myMod_form` function to have a place holder for your data. When the form is loaded, simply check to see if your temp holder is populated. if it is then you know you have a result and display it.

See code below.

```
function myMod_form($form, &$form_state) {

    ...

    if(!empty($form_state['temporary'])) {
        $form['results'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'item',
            '#markup'   => $form_state['temporary'], 
        );
    }

    return $form;
}

function myMod_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {
     ...

     $results = callSomeFunctionToGetResults();

     $form_state['temporary']   = $results;
     $form_state['rebuild']     = TRUE;

     ...
 }
```

i omitted all my code that would populated `$results` but this should get you to where you need to go.

***quick addition here.***

I just realized that you wanted it to go to another page and not the same page. I believe in your `myMod_submit` function you can use `drupal_goto()`. pass it a url and also pass it some options. you can then parse out the options as your values in the other page. See [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7). however, i haven't tested this option out.

Comment: It seems that this is exactly what I need, and  I wish also to stay on the same page, so  your example will probably do the trick.Will check on desktop and accept answer . Tnx

Answer (score 0):

If its a node form you can add an extra form submit handler to get the values Printed if not you probably have a submit function try [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

As its a form submit you should try [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)  OR [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    //drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state, 1).'</pre>');
    print_r($form_state, 1);
    die('Check the die !');
}
```

[Basic form with submit handler](http://drupal.org/node/717740)

[How do I add an additional submit handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/how-do-i-add-an-additional-submit-handler)

Comment: i can output the results this way, but i want to format them after submission, after page has been reloaded. So calculations done after form submit must be "remembered" and outputed in "next screeen". It is in fact module that operates in admin area.

Comment: I dont want to use drupal_set_message, rather to get calculation results and show it on the reloaded submission page

Comment: @HoverFusion see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to access variables outside the function in other function is to make the scope of the variable as [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $a;
  $a=$b+$c;    
}
```

And on submit, in other function you can access this variable by something like:

```
function some_page_load_function() {
  global $a;
  //print/format $a according to requirement.
}
```

I've written the function name to be `some_page_load_function`, as I'm not sure about the function you're wishing to access the value; as you also mentioned that this module might be a part of admin region.