# Commerce Product Display Node using Multiple Fields?

Tags: commerce, entities

Hello after reading [How do I display my products?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-do-i-display-my-products) I was impressed how easy it is to have a display node have a simple attribute system for a product.

For example Clothes can have a product reference field for different sizes.

For more complex use case can we have multiple fields?

For example Clothes size and color with each combination having a different product. I understand this requires many more products as a result.

Has anyone talked about this use case or know of a workflow / module here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. Just 2 list fields for your product type, 1 for color and 1 for size.

When creating your products, have the clothes of the same size use the same image.

When you create a product display node, you will see both of the select lists displayed. When you select a different color the image will change.

The issue I am having is that when selecting option 2 and then option 1, option 2 will reset back to its default value.  The risk is that a customer will not notice and order the wrong product.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc

Looks like the best way atm However there is still the UI problem of one select list between all the possible variations.

Ideally we need two select lists being displayed on the node for both attributes eg size and color.