# How to display 9 products WITH images on one page

Tags: commerce

I've managed to add products and even create a "Store" node that gives me a dropdown of my CDs. BUT, I have yet to figure out how to display all 9 products on that "store" node or, at the very least, have each product show a thumbnail image so that it's not just a plain dropdown menu.

In addition, I followed another tutorial that instructed me to create add content using the "Display" content type I created but this still only shows one product. {http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-do-i-display-my-products

Please help.

…Drupal Newbie…

Answer (score 1):

A Node is not a "Store", it's a Product display, meaning that it displays a group of Products that belong together (like t-shirts in different colors/sizes).

To have 9 separate products displayed on a page, you create 9 nodes and assign a product to each of them. Then you can for example build a view that lists them on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a view that displays 9 nodes of type Product. If you search for Views tutorials you should fine tons of examples. The series from nodeOne is probably the best

http://dev.nodeone.se/node/781